# parameter value missing sometimes when calling WCF method

Tags: wcf, session

my system have one simple function is to search order list by conditions and there are a lot of different conditions. One of the parameter value is getting from session value. like below code.

```
long Namekey = session.NameKey;
```

After prepared all search parameters, it will call one WCF method to do the searching, and inside the WCF method, it has one line code like below:

```
if (searchParam.NameKey > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.NameKey == searchParam.NameKey);
}
```

We suppose NameKey has value every time, since the value is getting from session, but in live version, some times the query didn't apply NameKey condition. **And this cannot be reproduced even on live version.**

It is very strange, and I already add log when founding NameKey is null or zero on page loading.

Does anyone can give me more clues/points how to continue investigate this? Does WCF has some tricky on this?

Thanks for your help!

--------------2016/10/14 add config---------------

```
<binding name="XXXXX" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: How do you get the searchParam? Could you post the service interface?

Comment: Also post your configuration.

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual, Thanks for your reply. I get other search param from page UI, which post to web server, then web server will call WCF service to do searching.

Comment: @William, which configuration you want to see? I add configs which is in web.config which configured for WCF service.